# How to update aspx page while using Multithreading

Tags: asp.net, .net, multithreading, webforms, asp.net-ajax

I am using multi-threading to update/display the content of page. Page is using multiple ( and nested ) update panels. Right now, i am using following **logic** to update page.

I have seven threads, each thread gets data by querying database  and display them in specific section of page. We start threads and wait for 2 mints, after passing 2 mints if some threads still working then we break those and display the populated data on page, these calls to thread are making on page load event.

**Problem** here is that we must need to wait for specific time before page load, and then after that time limit, page 'll be displayed with populated data. Users need to wait for long to see the page, which making a really bad impression.

If we remove the limit of 2 mints, then page rendered fast but it does not display all data.

**What i want here**, when we call threads, we don't need to wait for all, when one thread completes it should show its data on page, and as soon as other threads being complete then they should display their data accordingly.

Comment: have you looked at calling web methods/services via ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution of this problem after testing many techniques.

To implement this, we don't need to use threading. When we call a page, server makes an object of this page and perform all required executions and then it render this page, destroy its object on server and send rendered page to Client Browser. So after rendering we can't receive thread's response. To receive thread's response, we must have to stop page being rendered explicitly (it causes delay, which we don't want).

So our solution is using JSON Ajax API with Web Methods (with Serialization and Deserialization if you are dealing with complex objects).

We have to load page with all controls on it, onload event of page, call javascript method which call Web Method using JSON API, after receiving response from Web Method, we have to update respective controls using JavaScript/JQuery manually.