# How to update labels text using Multithreads

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, delegates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to update aspx page while using Multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861339/how-to-update-aspx-page-while-using-multithreading)

I want to update **Label** text while performing multithreading in asp.net web site, my code works fine, but it does not update **Label** text. When i debug it, then its working fine, and updating values of labels in code behind, but it does not effect font screen ( page ). My code is :

**.ASPX Code:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
        <br /> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
        Thread 1: <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>  <br /><br />
        Thread 2: <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label> <br /><br />
        Thread 3: <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label> <br /><br />
        Thread 4: <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label> <br /><br />
        Thread 5: <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label> <br /><br />
        Thread 6: <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label> <br /><br />
        Thread 7: <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label> <br />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
```

**.CS Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;

public partial class Default_test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public delegate string Delg_Method1(int a, int b);
    public delegate string Delg_Method2(int a, int b);
    public delegate string Delg_Method3(int a, int b);
    public delegate string Delg_Method4(int a, int b);
    public delegate string Delg_Method5(int a, int b);
    public delegate string Delg_Method6(int a, int b);
    public delegate string Delg_Method7(int a, int b);
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Waiting ...";
        Label2.Text = "Waiting ...";
        Label3.Text = "Waiting ...";
        Label4.Text = "Waiting ...";
        Label5.Text = "Waiting ...";
        Label6.Text = "Waiting ...";
        Label7.Text = "Waiting ...";
        callingAsynchMultiThreads();

    }

    #region Threads

    public void callingAsynchMultiThreads()
    {

        AsyncCallback method1Callback = new AsyncCallback(Method1Complete);
        Delg_Method1 dlg_call1 = new Delg_Method1(Load_Method1);
        IAsyncResult iar1 = dlg_call1.BeginInvoke(1, 0, method1Callback, null);

        AsyncCallback method2Callback = new AsyncCallback(Method2Complete);
        Delg_Method2 dlg_call2 = new Delg_Method2(Load_Method2);
        IAsyncResult iar2 = dlg_call2.BeginInvoke(1, 1, method2Callback, null);

        AsyncCallback method3Callback = new AsyncCallback(Method3Complete);
        Delg_Method3 dlg_call3 = new Delg_Method3(Load_Method3);
        IAsyncResult iar3 = dlg_call3.BeginInvoke(1, 2, method3Callback, null);

        AsyncCallback method4Callback = new AsyncCallback(Method4Complete);
        Delg_Method4 dlg_call4 = new Delg_Method4(Load_Method4);
        IAsyncResult iar4 = dlg_call4.BeginInvoke(1, 3, method4Callback, null);

        AsyncCallback method5Callback = new AsyncCallback(Method5Complete);
        Delg_Method5 dlg_call5 = new Delg_Method5(Load_Method5);
        IAsyncResult iar5 = dlg_call5.BeginInvoke(1, 4, method5Callback, null);

        AsyncCallback method6Callback = new AsyncCallback(Method6Complete);
        Delg_Method6 dlg_call6 = new Delg_Method6(Load_Method6);
        IAsyncResult iar6 = dlg_call6.BeginInvoke(1, 5, method6Callback, null);

        AsyncCallback method7Callback = new AsyncCallback(Method7Complete);
        Delg_Method7 dlg_call7 = new Delg_Method7(Load_Method7);
        IAsyncResult iar7 = dlg_call7.BeginInvoke(1, 6, method7Callback, null);


    }
    public string Load_Method1(int a, int b)
    {
        int temp = a + b;
        return temp.ToString();
    }
    public string Load_Method2(int a, int b)
    {
        int temp = a + b;
        return temp.ToString();
    }
    public string Load_Method3(int a, int b)
    {
        int temp = a + b;
        return temp.ToString();
    }
    public string Load_Method4(int a, int b)
    {
        int temp = a + b;
        return temp.ToString();
    }
    public string Load_Method5(int a, int b)
    {
        int temp = a + b;
        return temp.ToString();
    }
    public string Load_Method6(int a, int b)
    {
        int temp = a + b;
        return temp.ToString();
    }
    public string Load_Method7(int a, int b)
    {
        int temp = a + b;
        return temp.ToString();
    }

    public void Method1Complete(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Delg_Method1 dlgM1 = (Delg_Method1)((AsyncResult)ar).AsyncDelegate;
        //dlgM1.EndInvoke(ar);
        Label1.Text = dlgM1.EndInvoke(ar).ToString();


    }
    public void Method2Complete(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Delg_Method2 dlgM2 = (Delg_Method2)((AsyncResult)ar).AsyncDelegate;
        //dlgM2.EndInvoke(ar);
        Label2.Text = dlgM2.EndInvoke(ar).ToString();
    }
    public void Method3Complete(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1500);
        Delg_Method3 dlgM3 = (Delg_Method3)((AsyncResult)ar).AsyncDelegate;
        //dlgM3.EndInvoke(ar);
        Label3.Text = dlgM3.EndInvoke(ar).ToString();
    }
    public void Method4Complete(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Delg_Method4 dlgM4 = (Delg_Method4)((AsyncResult)ar).AsyncDelegate;
        //dlgM4.EndInvoke(ar);
        Label4.Text = dlgM4.EndInvoke(ar).ToString();
    }
    public void Method5Complete(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2500);
        Delg_Method5 dlgM5 = (Delg_Method5)((AsyncResult)ar).AsyncDelegate;
        //dlgM5.EndInvoke(ar);
        Label5.Text = dlgM5.EndInvoke(ar).ToString();
    }
    public void Method6Complete(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Delg_Method6 dlgM6 = (Delg_Method6)((AsyncResult)ar).AsyncDelegate;
        //dlgM6.EndInvoke(ar);
        Label6.Text = dlgM6.EndInvoke(ar).ToString();
    }
    public void Method7Complete(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3500);
        Delg_Method7 dlgM7 = (Delg_Method7)((AsyncResult)ar).AsyncDelegate;
        //dlgM7.EndInvoke(ar);
        Label7.Text = dlgM7.EndInvoke(ar).ToString();

    }


    #endregion

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the page life-cycle has finished and the page rendered / sent to the browser before the threads have finished updating their controls. During debug you can see the threads completing their work but are altering labels that have already been sent to the browser.

Once the page has been sent to the browser the server cannot then send a new version to the client without the client asking for a "new version". A possible way around this is to have the page constantly checking for updates via AJAX / JavaScript or similar so when the threads have finished the new values can be displayed.

A *VERY* simple example of updating page every 5 seconds using an `UpdatePanel` would be:

**Web Page (ASPX)**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updateView" runat="server" >
<ContentTemplate>

    <!-- Refresh the page automatically -->
    <asp:Timer ID="timAutoRefresh" runat="server" Interval="5000" OnTick="OnRefresh_Tick" />

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Code-Behind (.cs)**

```
protected void OnRefresh_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    // Check values and update page...
}
```

There are other ways and this is a very simple example. You should add labels into the same UpdatePanel as the timer and change the UpdatePanel so it only updates itself to minimise post-backs etc.

Comment: Yeah, you are right and i also know this life cycle, but problem is that, how can we do this? can you help me regarding this ?

Thanks

Comment: Hopefully this will get you started! If you like the answer please click the TICK and mark this as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: He told you already: "A possible way around this is to have the page constantly checking for updates via AJAX / JavaScript or similar so when the threads have finished the new values can be displayed."